# ReactJS: How to map items in conditional statements

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that allows a user to click a button in the header and add different input types.

```
export default class ElementContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="append-header">
        <Headline buttonCheck={this.props.buttonCheck} />
        <SubHeadline buttonCheck={this.props.buttonCheck} />
        <URLButton={this.props.buttonCheck} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm trying to implement `react-beautiful-dnd` into the project so that those inputs can be repositioned like a list in Trello.

Looking at that library (and other similar libraries), they use the data as lists in order to perform the drag and drop function.

The items in my app are added to the view by conditional rendering:

```
export default class InputShow extends Component {
  render() {
    const { node } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="editor-div" >
            {
              (node.type === 'buttonA') ?

                <textarea
                  //omitted code
                  id={node.id}
                  onChange={this.props.inputContentHandler} />
                   :
                 (node.type === 'buttonB')
                   ?
                 <URLButton
                   url={this.url}
                   id={node.id}
                   title={this.title}
                   />
                   :
                   ""
               }
       </div >
    )
  }
}
```

I've tried to map the items by creating a state for items (`additions`)

```
export default class InputShow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      additions: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { node } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="editor-div" >
        {this.state.additions.map(addition => (
          <div key={addition.id}>
            {
              (node.type === 'buttonA') ?

                <textarea
                  //omitted code
                  id={node.id}
                  onChange={this.props.inputContentHandler} />
                  :
                (node.type === 'buttonB')
                  ?
                  <URLButton
                   url={this.url}
                   id={node.id}
                   title={this.title}
                   />
                   :
                   ""
            }
          </div>
        ))}
      </div >
    )
  }
}
```

I didn't get any errors, however now when I click on the buttons, no data is being displayed in the view. I've done simple maps in the past with API and local data but I've never tried it with ternary statements. Thanks for any feedback on a solution to this problem.

Comment: I think you have login problem with your `node` prop, as there is no error in the code

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is separate the view logic from the code and create a functional component. Pass the values from the main as below:

```
{this.state.additions.map(addition => (
            return <CustomTemplate id={addition.id}
            nodeId={node.id} changeEvent={this.props.inputContentHandler}
            nodeType={node.Type} url={this.url} title={this.title}/>))}
```

Create CustomTemplate something like this

```
const CustomeTemplate =(props)=>(
use props to get the values in the templates
)
```